# Этимология слов "храбрость", "отвага", "смелость"

Tags: этимология, заимствования, переводы

Ищу наиболее подходящее слово перевод к английскому слову "сourage".

Английское слово происходит от слова "сor" — центр, ядро. Т.е. это внутренняя сила преодоления чего-то. А в русском языке?
Нашел только этимологию слова "храбрость": с иврита — ХР+АБР.
Вот тут написано интересно:
 https://www.proza.ru/2015/08/29/1618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Храбрый** – не боящийся    опасности, умеющий **преодолевать** страх.

Черных предполагает, что у слова **"храбрый"** и.-е. основа (s)kerb,  отсюда scarp (швед.) – **острый, резкий**, крутой,   scharf (нем.) – резкий, острый, упорный. (Перестановка начальных гласных: sk/ks, затем kch и  ch).

**2) Смелый** – от сметь, восходит к лат. **mos - воля, норов**.

**3) Отвага** – бесстрашие, мужество смелость.  "Отважный" (по Черных) родственно словам "важный, уважать" и восходит к др.-рус. **вага – вес**, важити - весить. (Поэтому "важный" в современном языке – это весомый).

Слово "отважный" отмечено в словарях в 1731 году, одно из значений в народной речи – опасный, сомнительный. Получается, что отважиться – это пойти на риск, предварительно **взвесив** (оценив) свои возможности.